# How to enable SSL usage when using local XML autodiscover file?

Tags: outlook-redemption

I use the Redemption library and I encountered a problem I can not solve by myself.
In my project, I use a local XML file to login to the Exchange server (Autodiscover service is disabled on the server and can not be enabled). For this purpose, I create an Outlook Autodiscover "PreferLocalXml" registry key value and a domain name value defining the path to the local XML file. Redemption works correctly, but for some reason it does not use SSL when sending requests to the server.
Is it possible to force SSL usage in this case? However, using Autodiscover (without local XML file) works fine (SSL is used). Thank you in advance for your help.

I tried setting RDOSession.ConnectEncryptData to true, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

But `PreferLocalXml` is supposed to point to a local file, not a web server, so SSL would not apply - the file is accesses using the file API.

Comment: This is clear to me. What I mean is that the LogonHostedExchangeMailbox method and the other methods do not use SSL if I specify a local xml file instead of using the Autodiscover service.

Comment: Redemption itself does not directly connect to the mailbox, MSEMS MAPI provider does. How do you know the connection is not using SSL?

Comment: You can see this using a traffic analyzer. The problem was solved by adding the mapiHttp protocol to the XML file:

`<Protocol Type="mapiHttp" Version="1">
   <MailStore>
      <InternalUrl>https://[SERVER_NAME]/mapi/emsmdb/?MailboxId=[MAILBOX_ID]@[DOMAIN_NAME]</InternalUrl>
   </MailStore>
   <AddressBook>
      <InternalUrl>https://[SERVER_NAME]/mapi/nspi/?MailboxId=[MAILBOX_ID]@[DOMAIN_NAME]</InternalUrl>
   </AddressBook>
</Protocol>`

Thank you for your feedback.